# How to get the id (not pk) from mongoengine models?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

my models

```
class Result(Document) :
    id = IntField()
    turn = IntField()
    url = StringField()
```

the id is not the primary key.

As you know, mongodb will generate a key named '_id'. So I use 'id' for another means.
But in the django, the id or pk are means the primary key.

So, how can I get the field I want from the mongodb through django?

THX~

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields Not sure whether calling id_ the PK field solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Currently `id` is reserved for the primary key - so can't be reused for a non primary key.